# STM32 - Can I subvert the cool context switching for interrupts?

Tags: stm32, interrupt

The STM32 family has fantastic interrupt service, they stack a whole slew of extra registers for you, and load the LR with an artificial return to properly unstack while looking for opportunities for tail chaining, aborted entry, etc etc.
HOWEVER....it is too damn slow.  I am finding (STM32F730Z8, 200 MHz clock, all code including handlers in ITCM, everything in GNU assembly) that it takes about 120-150 ns overhead to get into an interrupt.
I am still learning about these, used to the old ARM7 where you had to do it all yourself, however, in those chips, if you had a minimal handler you didn't need to stack much.
So -- can I "subvert" the context switching in hardware, and just have it leap to the handler at elevated priority, pausing only to fill the pipeline, and leaving me to take care of stacking what is needed?   I don't think so, and haven't seen a way to do it, but I'm working on an extremely tight time-sensitive realtime code, and interrupt switching is eating all my time budget.  I'm reverting to doing it all in low-code, polled, but I hate the jitter that gives me on response to pin edges.   Help?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is done in pure hardware and is the main defining feature of all "Cortex-M" processors, not just STM32.

150ns at 200MHz is 30 cycles.  You can probably get it quite a bit faster.

One way is to mark the floating point unit as unused each time you finish with it, and to set a core flag to tell it not to save the floating point registers. See [ARM application note 298](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f0352c0cafe527e86f5bc66?token=) for details.

Another method that you might try is to move your vector table and interrupt handler code to internal SRAM.  STM32 has a flash memory accelerator which avoids most wait states on internal flash by performing prefetch of sequential instructions, but an asynchronous interrupt will probably not benefit from this.

Comment: Hi Tom -    Thanks for responding.
I agree that is should be 30 cycles, but that is not what I see.  I have fiducial markers, spare pins turned on at entry into interrupt handlers, off at exit, and I look at them on the scope.
Floating point:  not using at all.
Everything is already moved to internal SRAM.  no wait states, all on ITCM.

Comment: @JeffCasey I can only suggest that you read the architecture reference manual and technical reference manual and calculate the exact number of cycles you expect it should be, and make a minimum reproducible example that the FAE can go back to ARM with.  Sadly I don't think they will listen to you unless you are ordering in very large volumes.

Answer (score 0):

> that it takes about 120-150 ns overhead to get into an interrupt.

It is not the truth at all

It takes 60ns as it takes 12 clock cycles.

Comment: Thanks!    That is what I thought also --  certainly what I read in references.   It is not what I saw on the scope, however.  I know that there are 12 cycles needed for pushing registers on the stack, but what about refilling the pipeline?  Also, is there more overhead delay in all the cool stuff that the hardware/microcode does behind the scenes, such as making decisions on truncating context saves and restores for tail chaining or late arrival truncation?  Those things can't occur in zero time.

Comment: @JeffCasey it does everything needed, then it is your code.. If you use HAL do not expect miracles